# Establish the sufficient condition $|g'(x)| < 1$ for convergence of an iteration using the Banach fixed point theorem?

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, banach-fixed-point

If $x_n = g(x_{n-1})$ is an iteration, it converges if $g$ is continuously differentiable and $|g'(x)| < 1$.

The Banach FPT says that if $T$ is a contraction on a complete metric space $X$ then it has a unique fixed points.

I'm having trouble with relating the two. I suppose it would be easier if we knew $g$ is a contraction because then $\frac{|g(x) - g(y)|}{|x-y|} \le \alpha < 1$ so that by taking $\lim y \to x$ we would have $|g'(x)|<1$.

Comment: Do you know the [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?

Comment: If your domain is compact, $|g'|$ attains a maximum $|g'(M)|< 1$, so everything works.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi do know the MVT, but I don't have a good sense for knowing when I need to use it. Can you please explain how?

Comment: @user319831 Nothing about the domain is said in the problem.

Comment: So you don't know where $g$ is defined?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi I assume it is over a complete metric space. The problem asks to use the theorem only.

Comment: Complete metric space? You are talking about derivatives. Be careful. I suspect your function is simply defined on an interval $[a,b]$. Please check carefully.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi will write the problem exactly as it appears in the text "A usual sufficient condition for the the convergence of an iteration $x_n = g(x_{n-1})$ is that $g$ be continuously differentiable and $|g'(x)| \le \alpha < 1$. Verify this by the use of the Banach's fixed point theorem."

Comment: Oh, that's **much different** than what you have said. $|g'(x)| \le \alpha < 1$ is much stronger than what you wrote. Just apply MVT and you immediately get that $g$ is a contraction.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Can you please post as an answer? I'm sorry for not providing useful information, I felt it was unnecessary.

Comment: @user319831 Would you mind at least editing your question accordingly so that future readers are not confused by an accepted answer to a wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the MVT, you have $|g(x)-g(y)| = |g'(c)| |x-y| \leq \alpha |x-y|$, for every $x$ and $y$, and $\alpha <1$, so that $g$ is a contraction. Assuming the domain of $g$ is a complete metric space, then you can apply Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: Can you please explain how the last inequality holds?

Comment: You wrote that $|g'(c)| \leq \alpha < 1$.

Comment: I think this is what needs to be established, not assumed as given.

Comment: Apologies for all the questions, I think I now understand what the problem was asking for. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I see now that the problem was the meaning of "sufficient condition". Hope now it's all clear!

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=[1,\infty)\subset \Bbb R$, which is a complete metric space.
The function $g\colon X\to X$, $x\mapsto x+\frac1x$ has $g'(x)=1-\frac1{x^2}$ so $|g'(x)|<1$ for all $x\in X$. But $g$ has no fixed point.

Comment: I'm confused. What additional condition do we need to arrive at the conclusion of the problem?